# Characterization of Partial Isometries

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

An operator $T$ is said to be a partial isometry if $||Tx|| = ||x||$ for all $x \in( \text{Kernel } T)^\perp$.

I need to prove that $T$ is a partial isometry iff so is $T^*$.

The following result can be employed-
$(\text{Ker }T)^\perp = \text{Closure}(\text{Range }T^*)$
and range of a partial isometry is always closed

Answer (score 2):

If $\|Tx\|=\|x\|$, then $$\langle T^*Tx,x\rangle=\langle x,x\rangle. $$ So, if $P $ is the orthogonal projection onto  $(\ker T)^\perp $, $$\langle (T^*T-P)x,x\rangle=0$$ for all $x $. By polarization, $T^*T=P $.

Conversely, if $T^*T $ is a projection, for any $x\in (\ker T)^\perp=(\ker T^*T)^\perp=\text {ran}\,T^*T $ we have  $$\|x\|^2=\langle x,x\rangle=\langle T^*Tx,x\rangle=\|Tx\|^2. $$

The two paragraphs above show that  $T $ is a partial isometry if and only if $ T^*T $ is a projection.

Finally, if $T^*T $ is a projection, then $$T^*TT^*T=T^*T.$$Multiplying by $T $ on the left and by $T^*$ on the right, we get $$(TT^*)^3=(TT^*)^2. $$ This shows that $\sigma (TT^*)\subset\{0,1\}$ and so $TT^*$ is a projection. It follows that  $T^*$ is a partial isometry.

Comment: Can you please explain what polarization actually is?

Comment: It's a [basic Hilbert space technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity#Complex_vector_spaces). In this case, $$\langle (T^*T-P)x,y\rangle=\tfrac14\,\sum_{k=0}^3i^k\langle (T^*T-P)(x+i^ky),x+i^ky\rangle.$$